# Save image in sharedObject

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

How to save an Image into `SharedObject`? I'm using `SharedObject` for save application state,It is working well for Text Object and `UIComponent`  well,but saving an `Image` create problem.It doesn't throw any error.

```
   userdiagram.imageData = zorder.getItemAt(i) as mx.controls.Image
   userdiagram.x        = (zorder.getItemAt(i)).x;
   userdiagram.y        = (zorder.getItemAt(i) ).y;
   userdiagram.height   = (zorder.getItemAt(i)).height
   userdiagram.width    = (zorder.getItemAt(i)).width
```

here userdiagram is class and imageData is a image type variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I save the Image as suggest link by Abhinav:

```
var data:BitmapData = new BitmapData((zorder.getItemAt(i) as mx.controls.Image).width, (zorder.getItemAt(i) as mx.controls.Image).height);
                data.draw((zorder.getItemAt(i) as mx.controls.Image));
                var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
                var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(data);

                userdiagram.x         = (zorder.getItemAt(i)).x;
                userdiagram.y         = (zorder.getItemAt(i) ).y;
                userdiagram.height    = (zorder.getItemAt(i)).height
                userdiagram.width     = (zorder.getItemAt(i)).width
                userdiagram.rotation    = (zorder.getItemAt(i)).rotation
                userdiagram.bytes = bytes;
                saveState.addItem(userdiagram)
```

But when I retrieve image from `sharedObject` create a image type object and use the following code:

```
var v:Object = _saveIn.data.value1.readObject();
p.source   = (v as ArrayList).getItemAt(i).bytes;
```

here p is Image class object and `(v as ArrayList).getItemAt(i)` is saved byte array location.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use byteArray to save the image in the sharedObject.

You can read more about it here : http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?306972-Saving-bitmaps-to-a-shared-object

Comment: what is the size of the image that you are saving?

Comment: From adobe documentation about SharedObject: "The default size limit is 100 KB, although it can be larger if the client allows it."